# Как запустить отдельное приложение в фоне Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что я не знаю как реализовать приложение, работающее в фоне Django. Дано: У меня есть Web-сервис, который может отдавать/принимать данные через API. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в фоне 24/7 отправлялись запросы (используя данные "клиентов") на стороннее API и собиралась статистика. Собрать статистику и отправить запросы - это не проблема. Но вот как этот процесс реализовать в фоне, чтобы он работал всё время пока сервер включён я не знаю. Буду рад любым советам/ресурсам

Comment: Не знаю подойдет ли, но можете попробовать на стороне хостинга запустить нужный скрипт по крону, указав время запуска. Если не ошибаюсь, то большая часть хостов разрешает запускать крон задачи не более чем на 12 часов, так что можно поставить запуск скрипта каждые 12 часов и 1 секунду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую посмотреть в сторону Celery + Django.

Celery — это простая, гибкая и надежная распределенная система для обработки большого количества сообщений, предоставляющая операции с инструментами, необходимыми для обслуживания такой системы.

## Запуск в фоне:

```
    python3 -m celery -A __name_queue__ beat -l info -f ./beat.log
```

Можно с supervisor:
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

```
    [program:celery_beat]
    command=/root/__project_dir__/bin/start_celery_beat.sh
    process_name=%(program_name)s
    numprocs=1
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    redirect_stderr=true
```

/root/**project_dir**/bin/start_celery_beat.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/__project_dir__/src/__src_dir__/
docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis
pwd
exec python3 -m celery -A __name_queue__ beat -l info -f ./beat.log
```

## Установка

```
pip install celery
```

Обычно я работаю с redis установленном через docker:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

## Настройка

/root/**project_dir**/src/**src_dir**/**project_name**/**init**.py

```
from .celery_serv import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

/root/**project_dir**/src/**src_dir**/**name_app**/tasks.py

```
from imitator_fedsfm.celery_serv import app


""" Задания выполняемые по расписанию """


@app.task
def query_api():
    """ Ваш код """
    pass
```

Каждые *пять минут* вызывать задачу (**name_app**.tasks.query_api)
/root/**project_dir**/src/**src_dir**/**project_name**/celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '__project_name__.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')

app = Celery('__name_queue__')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'imitator-search-updates': {
        'task': '__name_app__.tasks.query_api',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),
    }
}

app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
```

В настройках Django:
/root/**project_dir**/src/**src_dir**/**project_name**/settings.py

```
"""....."""

REDIS_HOST = ''
REDIS_PORT = ''
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```